# Entity Framework Raw Queries vs ADO.NET

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

My little application works with Entity Framework and my idea is to replace this framework with something faster: ADO.NET - because EF is built on top of it.

So I have a question: if I keep Entity Framework, but change only the requests to raw queries, will I have the same result in terms of **speed**?

Comment: Maybe, maybe  not. The only chance you have is if you can write better queries than EF.  Simple ones like this, nah.

Comment: This could be slower because you use `*` which means *all* columns will be loaded, whether you want them or not. A LINQ query may have a `select` clause that returns specific columns only

Comment: Any question of performance requires testing for your use cases. The query and execution will be the same (EF uses ADO.NET), but EF does the result mapping rather than you doing it. I would expect not meaningful performance difference but only you can test your code.

Comment: Performance is affected by *indexing*, not micro-optimizations like this. *Why* are you looking at raw queries? Did you encounter a performance issue? What is the *actual* problem?

Comment: (After edit). You've added a SQL Injection vulnerability: I suggest you stick to EF.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this is just an example, I mean my question is if I use the same query in both side ADO.NET and EF, will I have the same speed result

Comment: Another problem - EF can generate the appropriate JOIN statements to load related entities, or filter using related entity. *This* statement though only loads the root entity

Comment: @Richard the example I wrote is just an example I copied from internet, so the mistake was intentional

Comment: @MehdiSouregi this is a bad example then. Don't guess, use a profiler to see what is actually executed and *the execution plan*. BTW, you *did* introduce an injection vulnerability. And you *do* load columns that you don't need, so this will be slower at best

Comment: It makes zero sense to make performance optimisation based on 'idea'. Have you encountered an exact performance issue? Are you sure EF is the root cause? You have to answer these questions before even thinking about some micro-optimisations.

Comment: "was intentional": that makes it *worse*. (People copy from [SO] questions and answers without checking for caveats in comments.)

Comment: The equivalent EF query would use `.Where (entity=>listOfIDs.Contains(entity.ID))`. The generated SQL statement will probably have the *same* or better execution plan with what you posted here. Compare the execution plans, don't guess, or ask others to make wild guesses

Answer (score 2):

> Is this kind of queries the same as using plain ADO.NET in terms of
>   speed ?

No they are not. See https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/dapper-vs-entity-framework-vs-ado-net-performance-benchmarking/ and http://ppanyukov.github.io/2015/05/20/entity-framework-7-performance.html for example.

If you are interested in speed, you should lean towards a micro-ORM like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) or [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) (or Massive etc etc). They will give you performance **almost** as fast as raw ADO.NET, plus nice mapping functionality (i.e. populating properties that match the same name as your columns).

http://www.nullskull.com/a/1659/net-microorms--dapper-petapoco-and-more.aspx may be worth a read as well.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos !